# "Windows Sandbox failed to start, virtual hard disk files must be uncompressed and unencrypted"

Tags: windows, ntfs, compression, sandbox, windows-sandbox

I have Windows 10 Pro and I successfully installed Windows Sandbox. However, when I try to run it, it shows the following error:

[image]

My (physical) hard drive is indeed compressed (NTFS compression) and encrypted (BitLocker). Is there any way to make Windows Sandbox work on my system?

- I cannot disable BitLocker, but I'm hoping that when it says "encrypted" it means NTFS per-file encryption and not BitLocker.
- I could disable compression for the folder where the virtual hard disk files are stored, but where are those files stored?

Comment: The message might refer to the virtual environment file of Windows Sandbox. Try: (1) Ensure that the Windows Sandbox folder is uncompressed, (2) Uninstall Windows Sandbox, reboot, uninstall Hyper-V, reboot, then reinstall in reverse order.

Comment: Like I said, I want to try to disable compression, but I don't know which folder to uncompress.

Comment: I believe that Windows Sandbox is located in the folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Containers`.

Comment: Thanks! I disabled compression for that folder, and now it works :)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, so I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Sandbox is located in the folder
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Containers`.

This folder needs to be uncompressed for Windows Sandbox to function.